# 403, Error: User does not have sufficient permission for site---Google Search Console OAuth access token

Tags: python, oauth, http-status-code-403, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

We have been using OAuth 2.0 for authenticating google search console webmasters API.
we are mainly hitting two endpoints `/sites` and `/searchAnalytics/query` to fetch sites and sitemaps data.
Interestingly, the access_token which got generated using refresh_token is able to retrieve data for sites but not for sitemaps.
For sitemaps it's throwing error:

> HTTP-error-code: 403, Error: User does not have sufficient permission for site https://www.example.com See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999

This behaviour has started since June 4, 2022. Prior to that it's been working perfectly fine.

Comment: Sometimes the API key you're using in order to generate these tokens for your client have a TTL (Time To Live) mechanism set in place (not referring specifically to OAuth 2.0), I'd suggest to refresh your API key for OAuth 2.0, other than that, try to provide more details in your question.

Comment: @Holdsworth I believe its not the case of TTL. since the refresh token is able to generate access_token and generated access_token is able to retrieve data for /sites

Comment: Did you overview if there were any changes in permissions given to users/roles?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> User does not have sufficient permission for site

This error means that the currently authenticated user does not have permission to  access the site you are trying to retrieve data for.

For example the [sitesmaps.list](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/sitemaps/list) method will return a list of all sites that the currently authenticated user has access to.

While a [sitesmaps.get](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/sitemaps/get) method requires that you send a url of the site you would like to retrieve information for.

If the user who is currently authenticated  does not have access to that site then you will get the error you are getting.

The solution would be to authorize your application with a user who has access.  Or use a service account and configure delegation [Managing owners, users, and permissions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7687615?visit_id=637939110863084966-62861207&rd=2)